# Determining if a point is on which side of a line (explanation)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Source: http://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/machine-learning-classics-the-perceptron/

I asked this question on stack overflow, but I guess it is more appropriate here.

"The general equation of a line given two points in it, $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, is $A + Bx + Cy = 0$ where $A, B, C$ can be written in terms of the two points. Defining a vector $\mathrm{V} = (A, B, C)$, any point $(x,y)$ belongs to the line if $\mathrm{V}^\mathrm{T}\mathrm{x} = 0$, where $\mathrm{x} = (1,x,y)$. Points for which the dot product is positive fall on one side of the line, negatives fall on the other."

I can't seem to connect why this is true. Especially when the vector for V is defined as:

$\mathrm{V} = [(x_2*y_1)-(x_1*y_2), y_2-y_1, x_1 - x_2] $

Why is $Bx$ defined by $y_2-y_1$? Why does the Dot product, $\mathrm{V}^\mathrm{T}\mathrm{x} = 0$ work?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a line $y=mx+c$

$\implies y-mx-c=0$

Now consider a point $P(x_1,y_2)$ above this line. We know that for a particular value of $x_1$ the y value is given by  $y_1=mx_1+c$ but since $y_2$ considreed is greater than $y_1$ i.e, $y_2-y_1>0$ which implies

$y_2-(mx_1+c)>0$ Hence if the point lies above the line it is greater than zero and if it lies below it is less than zero by a similar argument.

Comment: I see, but what about the vector V. How does the inner product work?

Comment: He is substituting the matrix in place of $V=(A,B,C)$ not in place of $Ax$, $Bx$ and $Cx$. So now we have to find A B C after substituitng points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in the given equation, but if we do that we have two equations with three unknown I dont think we will be able to find the vaues of A,B and C. I am not sure whether i am correct or not.